# KafkaTransactionManager with Spring transaction annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka

We are trying to implement a kafka transaction through spring boot. And noticed some interesting things.

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {
    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Long, RatingProcessingMessage> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "transaction-");
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Long, Message> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

1. Here it is interesting, after set `ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG`, the auto configuration class `KafkaAutoConfiguration.class` should create the bean

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    name = {"spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix"}
)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager(ProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTransactionManager(producerFactory);
}
```

But it doesn't happen, so `spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix != ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG`

Сould not find a suitable constant in ProducerConfig.

2. For reasons unknown to me, when calling `kafkaTemplate.send()` in the transaction, we see in the log `JpaTransactionManager`

```
15:56:13.939 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] INFO  o.a.k.c.p.i.TransactionManager - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Invoking InitProducerId for the first time in order to acquire a producer ID
15:56:13.991 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Cluster ID: M-DqpGu4T_25jGui6701-w1
15:56:14.013 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  o.a.k.c.p.i.TransactionManager - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Discovered transaction coordinator localhost:9094 (id: 0 rack: null)
15:56:14.185 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  o.a.k.c.p.i.TransactionManager - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] ProducerId set to 5 with epoch 14
15:56:14.258 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.259 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-5 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.259 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-2 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.259 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-8 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.259 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-9 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.259 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-4 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.260 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-1 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.260 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-6 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.260 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-transaction-0] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Producer clientId=producer-transaction-0, transactionalId=transaction-0] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition event-rating-7 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to dEt3oJ_SQqW0Gz1mgPc5Fg
15:56:14.406 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
15:56:14.406 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1789264984<open>)]
15:56:14.511 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1789264984<open>)] after transaction
```

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class TestService {
    private final KafkaTemplate<Long, Message> kafkaTemplate;
    
    @Transactional
    public void test(Long id, Message message){
        kafkaTemplate.send("topic", id, message);
    }
}
```

As described above

1. I wonder why `KafkaTransactionManager` is not injected (**but it is important** that the transaction was successful without this bean)
2. For some reason `JpaTransactionManager` appeared in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot knows nothing about

```
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "transaction-");
```

Boot auto configuration requires you to set the property in application.yml/properties.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix

Instead of defining your own producer factory, let boot auto configure it for you.

You must also have enable JPA to get its TM.